# Java 8 string handling - replaceFirst and replaceAll

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a better way of doing this in Java8 e.g. with `Stream.of(...)`?

```
if (messageBody.startsWith("\n\n")) {
    messageBody = messageBody.replaceFirst("\n", "");
}
final String messageBodyFormatted = messageBody.replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
```

Comment: You can get rid of the condition by using: `replaceFirst("\n(?=\n)", "");`. I don't think Java 8 will give you more here.

Comment: Does this mean you want to leave heading/trailing spaces (not newlines) untouched?

Comment: @Maroun Maroun: that doesn’t have the same semantics as the `startsWith` check which requires the occurrence to be at the very start of the string. Fixing that, allows an even simpler solution: `replaceFirst("^\n\n", "\n")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s an option:

```
    if (messageBody.startsWith("\n\n")) {
        messageBody = messageBody.substring(1); // remove first newline
    }
    final String messageBodyFormatted = messageBody.replace("\n", "<br />");
```

Inside the if statement I’m simply removing the first char since I already know what it is. If you think it’s subtle, just use your own version instead. I changed the final `replaceAll()` with `replace()` — in spite of the name it does the same, only without regular expressions.

Comment: Indeed the box of java 8 need not be opened.

Comment: @JoopEggen, I agree. Streams are fun, but I wouldn’t dream of using them in this snippet.

Comment: The only thing different in Java 8 would be using Optionals in lieu of if-statements, and even then, it's only appealing if you _really_ don't like to define variables: Optional.of(messageBody).map(body -> body.startsWith("\n\n") ? body.substring(1) : body).map(body -> body.replace("\n", "<br />")).ifPresent(formatted -> { /* do something*/ })